# Why can't I attach custom fields to the journal with systemd-run --user?

Tags: debian, systemd

I want to run a program in a transient unit with [`systemd-run`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-run.html), using the **user-level** service manager (`--user`), with some custom fields attached to the journal.

According to [the docs](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#LogExtraFields=) I can use `LogExtraFields` to do this. So I am running the program and setting the custom field `FOO=bar`, like this:

```
$ systemd-run --user --property LogExtraFields="FOO=bar" sh -c "sleep 1 && echo henlo"
```

But when I check the journal entries for the transient unit, my custom label isn't there:

```
$ journalctl --user-unit run-rd8f0b861d11d4b13bcdae84e5a9d55cf.service -o verbose | grep FOO
$
```

However, when I try the same operation as *root* and use the **system-level** service manager, my custom field is indeed written to the journal:

```
$ sudo systemd-run --property LogExtraFields="FOO=bar" \
  sh -c "sleep 1 && echo henlo"
```

```
$ sudo journalctl --unit run-r75220e0f4e574ba292eb864c65d7f414.service -o verbose | grep FOO
     FOO=bar
```

Why is this the case? Do users need extra permissions to write extra fields into the journal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this the case? Do users need extra permissions to write extra fields into the journal?

Users don't, but the specific *mechanism* that systemd uses to supply the extra fields to journald is, currently at least, only aware of system-level units (and relies on write access to /run/systemd).

Although your user-level systemd manager *could* supply extra fields to journald directly, when creating the stdout-to-journal pipe for this service, this would only have effect on messages captured from stdout and stderr – but the fields couldn't be automatically attached if the service process itself submitted messages through /dev/log or through the "main" journald logging socket.

To solve that problem, systemd has chosen to have journald manually query systemd for the extra fields attached to the unit (as journald already knows<sup>1</sup> which unit the process belongs to) – but as currently implemented, only the system-wide service manager (pid1) is being queried for fields attached to user@1000.service; your user-level services are ignored.

<sup>1</sup> (With short-lived processes such as `echo` there's also the problem of the process exiting before journald can find out which unit it belongs to. Unlike e.g. the PID or UID, which are attached by the kernel to each socket message, the kernel developers are steadfastly refusing to attach cgroup membership data so journald needs to get it from /proc/<pid> after the fact. Which is why you might see `_SYSTEMD_UNIT=` missing from some messages.)

User processes can include custom fields (except privileged `_*` fields) if they submit messages directly through the main journald socket. (This is already done e.g. by GLib2 logging functions.) For example:

```
logger --journald <<EOF
MESSAGE=Hello!
FOO=bar
EOF
```

*(Ignore the `--sd-param` option if you find it in the manual; the "sd" does not refer to systemd – it's for structured data in the RFC 5424 "IETF Syslog" protocol.)*

Comment: What a detailed answer, thank you. Is that behaviour (that journald queries systemd for fields) documented somewhere?

Comment: I don't think so. It's an implementation detail, not an API.